# Playing music synchronously on multiple devices

Tags: android

I am making an app like Galaxy S4's Group Play. How can we play music synchronously on multiple devices?

Comment: It is possible, but it will require some advanced programming skills and you will need to make use of multiple technologies. - What devices are you planning on sharing through?

Comment: I am making this app and almost done it. but the song on multiple devices does not play synchronously as Group Play App do perfectly there is some milliseconds delay on other devices.

Comment: What you need to do is to create a small buffer, like 15 - 20 seconds, then you need a trigger on the devices that will alert each other when each song has fulled the buffer, the moment that buffer is full and all phones have received the trigger, the music should begin playing. It should take only a couple of seconds to full the buffer

Comment: m doing full buffer on another device like Device'B' before play song. then send a socket message from the device Device'A' which received on the Device'A' play already buffered song. but Device'B' play song with  millisecond delay.

Comment: Is the delay consistent or does the time vary?

If the delay is consistent then you can program in the delay on Device A

Comment: the delay is vary. It is not consistent.

Comment: Ok, try this, if the delay is happening due to a connection issue, ping Device B from Device A a few times, then calculate the average time of the ping and use that time as the delay playback time - That is, by the way, how GPS receivers work to provide an accurate speed, they calculate the delay using pings and then calculate the speed differential

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51325/discussion-between-mani345-and-lemuel-botha)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the demo project here's [a link](https://github.com/bryan-y88/Musics_Around)!
this demo project play music synchronously on multiple android devices.